# Excel VBA Distribute Specific Number of Columns Evenly Across Sheet Width

Tags: excel, vba

As the title suggests, I am attempting to distribute a specified number of columns evenly across a page (omitting the first column, which has its width determined by its contents via the `.AutoFit` property). I have tried determining the width of the columns (let's say 10 columns) in the printable area (based on the print gridlines, which returns 8.11 per column, so 81.1 for the 10 columns) and subtracting the width of the first column and setting the `.ColumnWidth` property of each of remaining the specified number of columns to `(81.1 - ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ColumnWidth)/10`. However, the last column or two end up outside the print grid lines. Any idea how I can get this to work?

Here is the exact code:

```
Dim FirstColWidth As Long
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").AutoFit
FirstColWidth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").ColumnWidth
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B:K").ColumnWidth = (81.1 - FirstColWidth)/10
```

Comment: Always helps to include the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You define FirstColWidth as `Long` - that means if the column width is e.g. 10.7 your calculation uses 10 - which definitly results in broader columns B-K than you want.

Try this code:

```vb
Sub setColumnWidth()

Dim wholeWidth As Single
wholeWidth = 81.1

Dim firstColWidth As Single
Dim restColWidth As Single

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With ws
    With .Columns(1)
        .AutoFit
        firstColWidth = .ColumnWidth
    End With
    
    With .Columns(2).Resize(, 10)
        restColWidth = (wholeWidth - firstColWidth)
    
        .ColumnWidth = restColWidth / 10
        
        'to be on the safe side it could be better to use as rounded value
        '.ColumnWidth = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(restColWidth / 10, 1)
        
        Debug.Print firstColWidth, restColWidth, (.ColumnWidth * 10) + firstColWidth
    End With
End With

End Sub
```